# What is the correct spelling of "X, schmX" to indicate dismissiveness (e.g., "evidence, schmevidence")?

Tags: etymology, american-english, orthography, prefixes

There is a curious construct in American English in which a word is stated and then repeated with the prefix "schm-" or "shm-" in order to indicate the speaker's dismissive attitude toward a concern that somebody else has. For example:

> "Smokers have lower life expectancies? Correlation, schmorellation—I'm going outside for another cancer stick."

Is the commoner or more "correct" spelling "shm-" or "schm-"? Is this construction used outside the US? What is its origin?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is called [*shm-reduplication*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schm):

> Shm-reduplication is a form of reduplication in which the original
>   word or its first syllable (the base) is repeated with the copy (the
>   reduplicant) beginning with shm- (sometimes schm-), pronounced /ʃm/.
>   The construction is generally used to indicate irony, derision or
>   skepticism with respect to comments about the discussed object:
>
> > He's just a baby!
> >  
> >     "Baby-shmaby". He's already 5 years old!

Per Wikipedia, both *shm-* and *schm-* constructions are acceptable. The [TV Tropes entry](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordSchmord) is interesting as well.

Comment: Alexis Manaster-Ramer's famous CLS paper on the topic is cited in the Wikipedia entry.